# .NET Developer to Blockchain Developer

Tags: career-switch

I have around 5 years of experience into .NET(Microsoft stack) and I have been offered BlockChain Developer role from BigFour firm. Is it common to make such tech stack switch with career or Is it wise to stick with one stack(.NET) ?. Experts please do throw some lights on the same.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How wise it is depends on your long-term goal, your preference and your ability to predict the future. There's nothing wrong with sticking to one technology your whole career, as long as the technology remains relevant. There's nothing wrong with switching, as long as the new technology remains relevant.

Comment: Rangesh you might consider rephrasing the question as "What sort of long-term career impact does switching stacks entail?" in order to be less "What should I do?"

Answer (score 1):

Whether any particular change in work area and tool set is a good career move for you at a given time depends too much on individual factors to be answerable.

It is definitely extremely unwise to plan to stick to one stack for a whole career. The problem is that the typical popular lifetime of a programming language or framework is much shorter than a human career.

For example, I got my first job in 1970, and retired relatively early in 2002, at age 53. In 2002 I was mainly using Java, Verilog, and Perl. I still do some open source programming, in C++. None of those existed in 1970. If I had been very, very lucky in 1970 I might have picked Fortran or COBOL, and still been employable in 2002. If I had stuck with the NCR assembly language programming I was doing on my first job it would not have gone so well.

One of the riskiest career moves possible is to become so wedded to a particular technology that you cannot learn something different. Your career then depends on that particular technology continuing to be important for the rest of your working life.

On the other hand, develop flexibility and life-long learning and you can be reasonably sure of staying employable across technology changes.

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts...

- You will be taking a step back in (effective) seniority, because you're learning something new, and the deep dotnet knowledge you have is less relevant.  Things like... which libraries are good?  What are the tough spots?  You'll need to relearn these.
- You're betting on blockchain becoming a big deal.  May be right, may not.  Either way, the experience you get will be useful.

The short story is that switching stacks won't really harm you in terms of your long-term career.  I'm a hiring manager, and I like to see people with broad experience.  It's really a question of **your preference**.  Is blockchain exciting enough to you that you're willing to put up with a steep ramp-up?

Answer (score 0):

How long is a piece of string?

Where do you want to go?

Blockchain is a hot topic - they look for people quite urgently at the moment.

But your career goal is your career goal, not our discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not asking if i should switch to blockchain ? My question is more towards pro /cons of career switch / tech switch you make along your career ?